# Period + に + frequency

Tags: grammar

I'm looking at JLPT4/5 grammar list and see such grammar point. But I can't find any information about it (truthfully I don't know how to).

Though I found some examples:
1 shuukan ni ikkai - once a week
1 nen ni 3 kai - 3 times a year

Can someone explain this or point me to where I can get that information? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking for help on the pattern, or just other explanations and materials?  Because there's not much to it really.  You know that `に` has multiple meanings, including "in" or "within".  So it's a pretty straight translation.

<Period> + に + <frequency>　→　"Within <period>, <frequency> times."  or  "<frequency> times in <Period>"

> - １年に３回　→　3 times within 1 year
> - 一週間に１回　→　Once per week